# SQLAlchemy - operate with primary key instance inside model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to generate some unique URLs from IDs with the purpose of appending at the end of some endpoints. The result will be something like .../32dwr4. I would like to insert these short urls into the database on instantiation, based on the primary key id.

I do not know if there is some kind of 'flushing' for operating inside the model:

```
class Storm(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _url = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)

    ## Relationships

    @hybrid_property
    def url(self):
        return self._url

    @url.setter
    def _set_url(self, plaintext):
        self._url= base64.b64encode(plaintext)

    def __init__(self, name, question, *):
        self.name = name
        self.question = question
        self.url = self.id  # <<------ is it possible to pass its id on the fly, convert it through the setter and store it?
```

If it is not possible, which approach do you recommend?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/yy7NfS5iTe4

Comment: Thank you so much. That give me multiple solutions, but i cannot identify a good solution taking into account that i want to separate models.py from session (called in views)... i am reading this http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_events.html but same problem i think. It needs to bind the event to a session. Any idea ? right now i just created a new method that i called after init:     def 
    def addurl(self, storm_id):
        self.url = str(storm_id).encode()